# Remove /Add class to to body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fall in problem I have a div which I want to display on button and hide on clicking any where else . But clicking within the body of div class get hidden too which I did not want .

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li> test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li> <button>click</button>
<div id="test" class="hidden">
     <ul>
       <li> test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>

<script>
$('botton').click(function(){
  $('#test').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('body').click(function(){
  $('#test').addClass('hidden');
});

</script>
```

How I can disable adding `hidden`  class by clicking within the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding hidden class when clicking inside the div, you can check whether the click event is from an element inside div or not, before adding the hidden class back. jQuery.closest() can be used for this purpose.

```
$('body').click(function(event){
if ($(event.target).closest('#test').length == 0)
  $('#test').addClass('hidden');
});
```

As MysterX pointed out, $('botton') should be fixed as $('button') first.

Answer (score 1):

Use stopImmediatePropagation: '*Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree*.' [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  $('#test').removeClass('hidden');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('body').click(function(e){
  $('#test').addClass('hidden');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: This is not a good solution if, for example clicks are tracking to the database

Comment: @MysterX - what database are you referring to?

Comment: I'm not reffering to any database, I said, if you use one of many differrent user activity trackers, this clicks will be not tracked to an analitycs dashboard

Comment: @MysterX - You're presuming stuff that wan't mentioned in the OP, namely 'database' and now an 'analitycs [sic] dashboard'.

Comment: Try to think some widely than the question is. But okay, for exectly this question your solution works. I gave you a plus

Comment: @MysterX - Thanks for the upvote; I understand your concern but trying to pre-empt nuances of a question is beyond the scope of succinct brevity.

Answer (score 1):

First: You have `botton` instead of `button`

Second: solution of your problem is to check which element was clicked:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#test').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('body').click(function(event){
    if(!$(event.target).is('button')){
        $('#test').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```